# PyPy — Doesn't create the XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, pypy

Why PyPy module doesn't work with xml.etree.ElementTree.
I create a test program:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def ToXML():
    root = ET.Element('test')
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write('output.xml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ToXML()
```

When I run this program with default Python interpreter (i use Python 2.7) it works, the file output.xml is created, but when I use Pypy it doesn't work.
Why?

Comment: What steps have you taken to try and debug this issue?  Have you tried to print progress to the console to see what is going wrong?  Have you tried modifying it to write to stdout instead of a file and see if that works?

Comment: Try recomping the module using `pypy` this way it will install in pypy. This is a guess. As this has worked for me in case of different python versions.

Comment: Your example works out of the box for me (PyPy 2.2.*).

Comment: Works now, xml file is created, but not in the folder with the code, only in the folder Pypy
I chage directory in tree.write and now works :D